# Please guide me to solve the following question from Sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality, proof-writing

**The question is :**

Suppose ${\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty}$ is a sequence, ${x \in \mathbb{R}}$, and ${x_n \ne x}$ for all ${n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Suppose the limit

L =  ${ \lim_{n\to \infty}}$ ${\dfrac{|x_{n+1} - x|}{|x_n - x|}}$

exists and L $\lt$ 1. Show that ${\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty}$ converges to x.

**The problem I faced :**

My intuition says to use ratio test as here ${\dfrac{|x_{n+1}- x|}{|x_n - x|}}$ form is given.

From the given information **i.e**,
L =  ${ \lim_{n\to \infty}}$ ${\dfrac{|x_{n+1} - x|}{|x_n - x|}}$,

we get,

${ \lim_{n\to \infty}}$ ${|x_{n+1} - x|}$ = L ${( \lim_{n\to \infty}}$${|x_n - x|)}$.

which implies,

${ \lim_{n\to \infty}}$ ${|x_{n+1} - x|}$ ${\lt}$ ${( \lim_{n\to \infty}}$${|x_n - x|)}$.

Now how to find for any ${\epsilon \gt 0}$, there exists an M ${\in \mathbb{N}}$, such that

${|x_n - x| \lt \epsilon}$.

Please suggest me a method to prove the statement.